# Datatable aoColumnDefs is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue with Datatable .

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <c:forEach items="${Details.columns}" var="column">
                                                <th>${column.columnTitle}</th>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <c:forEach items="${Details.columns}" var="column">
                                                <th></th>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <c:forEach items="${Details.callList}" var="call">
                                            <tr>
                                                <c:forEach items="${call.attributes}" var="attribute">
                                                    <td>${attribute.value}</td>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
$("#example1").dataTable({
            'sDom': '"top"i',
            //"aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSearchable": true, "aTargets": [1] }],
            "bPaginate" : true,
            "bLengthChange" : false,
            //"bFilter" : true,
            "bSearchable": true,
            "bSort" : true,
            "bInfo" : true,
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "iDisplayLength": 5 
            //}).columnFilter({"aoColumns": [{ "type": "text" }, { "type": "text" }, null]});
        }).columnFilter({"aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSearchable": true, "aTargets": [2] }]});
```

From the above snippet.. i am trying to remove the filter/search for last column alone.

Here "aoColumns" works as expected - It removes the filter in last column as i coded,
However i am unable to use "aoColumns" . Since the columns in this table is dynamic/configurable, so it is tough for me to change the code everytime.

It would be really grateful if anyone can help me here..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use Datatables and it works like a charm. I don't do sorting at client-side, I do it at server-side using AJAX, but the configuration for the table should be the same except for "bServerSide=true". Let me know if this solves your problem:

```
 var oTable = $('#tblMainTable').dataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem('jobTitlesDataTables', JSON.stringify(oData));
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jobTitlesDataTables'));
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 2000,
        "bServerSide": true, // server side 
        "sAjaxSource": BASE_URL + "Job/GetJobTitleMappingDTOs", // AJAX URL
        "bProcessing": true,
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
// send data from client-side to server-side
            aoData.push({ "name": "IsMapped", "value": $("#bdgIsMapped").data("selected") });
            aoData.push({ "name": "IsSearchableOption", "value": $("#bdgIsSearchable").data("selected") });
            aoData.push({ "name": "timestamp", "value": new Date().getTime() }); // Added to avoid caching in some IE versions.

            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "GET",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "cache": false,
                "success": function (json) {
                    // shows records count next to the top title
                    if (json.iTotalRecords > 0) {
                        $("#resultsDescription").text(" - " + json.iTotalRecords + " rows.");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#resultsDescription").text(" - No results.");
                    }
                    // shows paginator when necessary
                    if (json.iTotalRecords > json.iDisplayLength) {
                        $(".dataTables_paginate").show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".dataTables_paginate").hide();
                    }
                    $("#isFirstSearch").val("false");

                    fnCallback(json);
                }
            });
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            sType: "numeric",
            mData: "RowNumber",
            aTargets: [0],
            mRender: function (data, type, full) {
// this is for custom rendering a column just in case you need it
                // 'full' is the row's data object, and 'data' is this column's data
                return '<span class="RowNumber">' + full.RowNumber + '</span>';
            }
        },
        {
            sType: "numeric",
            mData: "JobTitleId",
            aTargets: [1],
            mRender: function (data, type, full) {
                // 'full' is the row's data object, and 'data' is this column's data
                return '<span class="EditableJobTitleId" data-job-title-id="' + full.JobTitleId + '">' + full.JobTitleId + '</span>';
            }
        },
        {
            sType: "string",
            mData: "JobTitle",
            aTargets: [2]
        }
],
        "order": [[1, "asc"]] 
    });
```

Comment: Could you let me know, How i can disable search/ filter in particular column in DataTable? and above is my code which is not worked so..

Comment: I don't know how to make one column not searchable. I prefer to deactivate that feature for all the columns and define custom filters outside the table because it gives me more flexibility even though it requires more work.